# Prove that for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^3,\lVert x \times y \rVert^2 = \lVert x \rVert^2 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove  that for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^3,\lVert x \times y \rVert^2 = \lVert x \rVert^2 \lVert y \rVert^2 - \langle x,y \rangle^2$

Use this identity to show that for $x,y \neq 0$, with the angle $\alpha$ between x and y it follows that:

$\lVert x \times y \rVert = \lVert x \rVert  \lVert y \rVert  \sin(\alpha)$

I don't have any idea for a starting point, can someone help me prove these please?

Comment: What is your definition of $x\times y$? Also, your relation with $\sin \alpha$ is wrong.

Comment: The usual definition of $x×y$ in terms of their components is $(x×y)_1=x_2y_3-x_3y_2$ etc. Then square the components and take their sum. Now write the right hand side in terms of the components and after some rearranging you find that it equals the left hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The High-Tech Way**

Let me use the definition that $x \times y$ is the unique vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$
 \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^3, \quad \det(x,y,z) = \langle x \times y,z\rangle.
$$
Since the result is trivial if $x$ or $y$ is zero, let's assume that $x$ and $y$ are both non-zero.

The trick will be to apply Gram--Schmidt to construct an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ out of the not necessarily orthonormal basis $\{x,y,x \times y\}$. Start with
$$
 e_1 = \frac{1}{\|x\|}x.
$$
Next, let
$$
 e_2 = \frac{1}{\|y - \langle e_1,y\rangle e_1 \|}(y- \langle e_1,x\rangle e_1)
$$
be the normalisation of the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto $\{x\}^\perp = \{e_1\}^\perp$. Finally, since $x \times y$ is orthogonal to $\operatorname{span}\{x,y\} = \operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$,
$$
 x \times y - \langle e_1,x \times y\rangle e_1 - \langle e_2, x \times y \rangle e_2 = x \times y,
$$
so set
$$
 e_3 = \frac{1}{\|x \times y\|} x \times y.
$$
Then $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$
 x = \|x\|e_1, \quad y = \langle e_1,y\rangle e_1 + \langle e_2, y \rangle e_2, \quad x \times y = \|x \times y\|e_3.
$$
But now, by multlinearity of $\det$,
$$
 \|x \times y\|^2 = \langle x \times y, x \times y \rangle = \det(x,y,x\times y)\\
=\det\left(\|x\|e_1,\langle e_1,y\rangle e_1 + \langle e_2,\|x\times y\|e_3 \right)\\
 = \|x\| \langle e_1,y\rangle\|x \times y\|\det(e_1,e_1,e_2) + \|x\|\langle e_2,y\rangle\|x \times y\|\det(e_1,e_2,e_3),
$$
so that, since $\det$ is antisymmetric and $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis,
$$
 \|x \times y\|^2 = \|x\|\langle e_2,y\rangle\|x \times y\|,
$$
and hence
$$
 \|x \times y\| = \|x\|\langle e_2,y\rangle.
$$
But now, recall that $y \in \operatorname{span}\{x,y\} = \operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$. Thus,
$$
 \|x \times y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 \langle e_2,y\rangle^2 = \|x\|^2(\|y\|^2 - \langle e_1, y\rangle^2) = \|x\|^2\left(\|y\|^2 - \frac{\langle x,y\rangle^2}{\|x\|^2}\right)\\
 = \|x\|^2\|y\|^2 - \langle x,y\rangle^2,
$$
as required.

Now, if you know that $\langle x,y \rangle = \|x\|\|y\|\cos\theta$, what can you conclude about $\|x \times y\|$? Note that the expression you wrote down for $\|x \times y\|$ in terms of $\sin\theta$ is actually wrong...

---

**The Low-Tech Way**

Let $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$, and recall that
$$
 x \times y = (x_2y_3 - x_3y_2,x_3y_1-x_1y_3,x_1y_2-x_2y_1).
$$
Then,
$$
 \|x\|^2\|y\|^2 - \langle x,y\rangle^2 = (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2) - (x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3)^2\\
 x_1^2y_1^2 + x_1^2y_2^2 + x_1^2y_3^2 + x_2^2y_1^2 + x_2^2y_2^2+x_2^2y_3^2 + x_3^2y_1^2 + x_3^2y_2^2+x_3^2y_3^3 - x_1^2y_1^2 -x_1y_1x_2y_2 - x_1y_1x_3y_3 - x_2y_2x_1y_1 - x_2^2y_2^2 - x_2y_2x_3y_3 - x_3y_3x_1y_1 - x_3y_3x_2y_2 - x_3^2y_3^2\\
 = x_2^2y_3^2 - 2x_2y_3x_3y_2 + x_3^2y_2^2 + x_3^2y_1^2 - 2x_3y_1x_1y_3 + x_1^2y_3^2 + x_1^2y_2^2 - 2x_1y_2x_2y_1 + x_2^2y_1^2
 = (x_2y_3 - x_3y_2)^2 +(x_3y_1-x_1y_3)^2+(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2\\
 = \| x \times y\|^2,
$$
as was claimed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, thats a beautiful proof and I appreciate the time you put into this. We haven't covered the gram-schmidt algorithm yet and the proof is probably harder than what would be expected from us, so I think there must be an easier way. Thanks again though.

Comment: Besides some super-slick geometric argument I can't imagine at the moment, the only alternative is plug in the explicit algebraic expressions for everything into
$$
\|x \times y\|^2 - \|x\|^2\|y\|^2 + \langle x, y \rangle^2
$$
and just chug away at the algebra until you're just left with $0$.

Comment: @eager2learn I've added the low-tech proof, which should be entirely elementary; the problem is that it's completely devoid of conceptual content.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was working on this as well. I actually think that this is what our prof wants us to do, since it's explicitly mentioned that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, but I agree that it's not a useful way at all to prove this result.

Answer (score 0):

As a point of interest, though almost certainly not the way you're intended to solve the problem, this is a trivial question when attacked with clifford algebra:

Define the "geometric product" of vectors as an associative product:  $x(yz) = (xy)z$ for instance.  Define $xx = x \cdot x = x^2$ and, for $a, b$ orthogonal, $ab = -ba$.  Define the grade of a product as the least number of orthogonal vectors that produce the same overall product.  For instance, if $a, b, c$ are all mutually orthogonal, then the product $abc$ is a grade-3 "multivector".

Result:  for any $x, y$, the geometric product $xy$ can be broken down as follows:

$$xy = x \cdot y + x \wedge y, \quad x \cdot y = \langle xy \rangle_0, \quad x \wedge y = \langle x y \rangle_2$$

where $\langle A \rangle_n$ denotes the grade-$n$ part of a multivector.

---

Given all these definitions, consider $xyyx$:

$$xyyx = x (yy)x = x (y^2) x = x^2 y^2$$

But, the product is associative, so you can group the vectors differently:

$$xyyx = (xy)(yx) = (x \cdot y + x \wedge y) (x \cdot y + y \wedge x)$$

It follows from the properties of the product that $x \wedge y = - y \wedge x$, so the result is

$$xyyx = (x \cdot y)^2 - (x \wedge y)^2 = x^2 y^2$$

On its face, this seems to run counter to the instructed result.  That's not the case:  it turns out that any 2-vector of the form $x \wedge y$ will *always* square to a negative number under the product.  (Consider:  for $a, b$ orthogonal, $abab = -abba = -a^2 b^2 < 0$.)

So, written in terms of magnitudes, we get

$$(x \cdot y)^2 + |x \wedge y|^2 = |x|^2 |y|^2$$

The magnitude of the "wedge product" is exactly that of the cross product, which is a whole topic in unto itself.